# How can I locate the line causing a crash in Xcode4.2 with iOS5?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, xcode4.2

When I use Xcode4.1 with iOS4, it works fine.
But when I use Xcode4.2 with iOS5, it locates at the main method.
So I don't know where in the program caused the crash.

Comment: Can you at least share with us what the crash message is?

Comment: But I am not talking about a specific crash.In a same case,Xcode4.1 can find where cause the crash,while Xcode4.2 just point to the main method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a breakpoint for all exceptoins

Command+6
Click + on the bottom left
Add Exception Breakpoint
Click Done

I am not sure why they changed the old behavior.

Comment: I added this but the behaviour is the same while debugging on device, I cannot see where the crash is. Which debugger are you using?  Thank you!!